# Preview Facebook Messenger's message on lock screen

Tags: lock-screens, facebook-messenger

I had this feature on for like 24 hours, but now it's gone. It's when Facebook messages would pop up onto my lock screen and I could see the message without having to actually turn on and unlock my phone. Now I cannot find how to change this.

Where is the setting for this feature?

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed the same thing.

It appears the latest Facebook updates have actually removed the feature as there is no setting in the app for the lockscreen.